# Child above object that is above the Child's Parent and above an other object

Tags: html, css

I want the div `#under_child_above_parent` under `#child` but above `#parent` and above `#under_all`. Is this possible with this HTML formatting? Because I need to have it formatted like this due to easier positioning of a complicated thing within child.

```css
#under_all {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:2;
}

#under_child_above_parent {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:3;
}

.objectwithinobject {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    top:100;
}

#parent {
    background-color:green;
    z-index:1;
}

#child {
    background-color:grey;
    color:yellow;
    z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<div id="under_all">
</div>
<div id="under_child_above_parent">
    Has to go above #under_all (blue), under#parent (green) and under #child (grey).
</div>
<div id="parent" class="objectwithinobject">
    <div id="child" class="objectwithinobject">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could achieve this by removing the `z-index:1;` from `#parent` div.

```css
#under_all {
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    z-index:2;
}

#under_child_above_parent {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
    z-index:3;
}

.objectwithinobject {
    width:50%;
    height:50%;
    position:absolute;
    left:25%;
    top:0px;
}

#parent {
    background-color:green;
}

#child {
    background-color:grey;
    color:yellow;
    z-index:4;
}
```

```html
<div id="under_all">
</div>
<div id="under_child_above_parent">
    Has to go above #under_all (blue), under#parent (green) and under #child (grey).
</div>
<div id="parent" class="objectwithinobject">
    <div id="child" class="objectwithinobject">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And how would you do it if `#under_child_above_parent` needs z-index because there is another div under that? Just realised that's what I have in the original thingy.

Comment: Edited the post now, sorry mate.

Comment: @DaanHeskes Where you want your `#under_all` div? Like this demo - http://jsfiddle.net/gomznc27/

Comment: Yes, exactly like that, thanks a lot for the help. :)

Comment: I just realised it didn't work because the object #under_all has a position set to fixed. Is is impossible to do this while the #under_all has a fixed position instead of an absolute one? Because I was making my website parralax. Now I don't have it fixed anymore though, thanks for the help.